# Store Azure Cache Access Key for WebSite

Tags: asp.net, caching, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-caching

i have a Website running on Azure Website(s).

Now i want to store the ASP.NET Sessions in the (new) Managed Cache.

As i deploy to one Staging Installation in North Europe and one Live Installation in West Europe i have to store the Access Key in the web.config.

But as the web.config(transfoirmation) is the same for both destinations i would like to have the Access Key anywhere within the app settings/anywhere else.

How can i seperate the two Access Keys/Cache URls within one Deployment?

Kind regards

Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it easiest to make another publish setting which makes another transformation. This way when you publish you will always have the correct caching credentials.

Comment: I already have 2 Publishing Settings, one for the Deployment to Dublin, one for the Deployment to Amsterdam, but the web.config-transformations are for release/debug and cannot detect which Deployment Setting is used.

Comment: Hi, so i got it: i had to create 2 new configs in VS, and there i had 2 new transfoamtions which holds the Cache Settings.